# Python: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, object, int

I am getting an error here and I am wondering if any of you can see where I went wrong. I am pretty much a beginner in python and can not see where I went wrong.

```
temp = int(temp)^2/key
for i in range(0, len(str(temp))):
    final = final + chr(int(temp[i]))
```

"temp" is made up of numbers. "key" is also made of numbers. Any help here?

Comment: `temp` is an `int`, so you can't write `temp[i]`

Comment: `final = final + chr(int(temp[i]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but num^2 does not mean num squared, it means num xor 2. If you want a power, you have to use the ** operator, i.e. int(temp)**2/key. If you meant to use xor, ignore this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you defined `temp` as an integer (also, in Python, `^` isn't the "power" symbol. You're probably looking for `**`):

```
temp = int(temp)^2/key
```

But then you treated it as a string:

```
chr(int(temp[i]))
        ^^^^^^^
```

Was there another string named `temp`? Or are you looking to extract the `i`th digit, which can be done like so:

```
str(temp)[i]
```

Comment: that just throws: `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @user1580845 Right, that will throw an error if you don't wrap the `str(temp)[i]` call in an int call, but a better answer can't be given because it's really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the `i`th number of temp, which is an integer, and get the char that the number represents and assign it to a string.

Comment: `final = final + chr(int(temp[i]))` becomes `final = final + chr(int(str(temp)[i]))`.

Also, `final = final + ...` can be `final+=`

Answer (score 0):

```
final = final + chr(int(temp[i]))
```

On that line **temp** is still a number, so use `str(temp)[i]`

**EDIT**

```
>>> temp = 100  #number
>>> str(temp)[0] #convert temp to string and access i-th element
'1'
>>> int(str(temp)[0]) #convert character to int
1
>>> chr(int(str(temp)[0]))
'\x01'
>>>
```

Comment: `final = final + chr(str(temp)[i])`
throws:
`TypeError: an integer is required`